# angular-datatables using promise and a json object does not display the data

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-datatables

I am using `angular-datatables` v0.5.x and I would like to load a local JSON object.  Based on my research I know that I have to use a [promise](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withPromise). From my `console.log` I can see that the `deferred.promise` is populated with the json data.  So I assume it is returned correctly to `DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise()`.  However none of the data is displayed in the data table.  Any help would be very appreciated!
HTML:

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-instance="dtInstance" class="row-border stripe compact hover">
</table>
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
var getTableData = function(jsonObj) {
    console.log('get table data function');
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(jsonObj); 
    console.log(deferred.promise);
    return deferred.promise;
};

$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(getTableData(jsonObj))
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');

$scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('col1').withTitle('Column 1'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('col2').withTitle('Column 2'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('col3').withTitle('Column 3'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('col4').withTitle('Column 4')
                    ];
 $scope.dtInstance = {};
```

The json object:

```
[{
    "col1": "Column 1",
    "col2": "Column 2",
    "col3": "Column 3",
    "col4": "Column 4"
}]
```

Comment: I don't see any `$scope.dtOptionsTransactionsByPOS`, neither this nor `$scope.dtColumnsTransactionsByPOS`. Even the dtinstance is incorrect, you are assigning undefined values to your datatable, hence it can't work in any way.

Comment: Im sorry, I changed the names for the example.  Those should be dtOptions, dtColumns, dtInstance.  I will edit it.

Answer (score -1):

Does your table expect the columns to be provided as an object or as an array of objects?

I see that your JSON object your passing to the table is an array of objects!

Try passing

```
{
    "col1": "Column 1",
    "col2": "Column 2",
    "col3": "Column 3",
    "col4": "Column 4"
}
```

or else change

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(getTableData(jsonObj))
.withPaginationType('full_numbers');
```

to

`$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(getTableData(jsonObj[0]))
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');`

Comment: I hope it will be an array of objects.  Otherwise I could not add multiple lines to the datatable.  Since I am only testing I only have one object.

Comment: You should **always** pass an array of objects to dataTables, no matter what kind of datasource you are using, remote or not, plain JSON or complex server-response. The only exception is that you can pass an array of array of strings, merely for backward compatibility. This is simply how dataTables works.